# 0x: Query Liquidity Pools for APR

Tags: javascript, 0x, fantom

Is there a way to use 0x to query LPs to find out their current APR? I'm trying to build a small reporting tool and would love to query LPs on these DEXes, but can't seem to figure out how. I tried going at the Uniswap contracts directly, but couldn't find a way, now I'm wondering if I can use 0x instead ...

https://www.liquiddriver.finance/farms
https://www.oxdao.fi/
https://spookyswap.finance/farms
https://app.spiritswap.finance/#/farms/allfarms

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Our API endpoints don't return the APRs for LPs. We focus aggregating liquidity for [swaps](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references) and offering & taking 0x limit orders via [orderbook](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-orderbook/api-references/get-orderbook-v1).
Hope you find another suitable tool.